# How do I create a list in a separate Dataframe column from specific values from within a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension, apply

I have a Dataframe called `'new_api_df'` with a column called `new_api_df['Categories']` that contains a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 1953, 'SectionId': 1256, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Filters.No Sale Made', 'Weight': 1.0}
, {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2016, 'SectionId': 1255, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Imported.Objections', 'Weight': 3.0}
, {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2017, 'SectionId': 1255, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Imported.Touting Benefits', 'Weight': 1.0}
]
```

I want to take every 'BucketFullName' and place those values into a list in a separate column `new_api_df['category_list']` as such:

`['Categories.Filters.No Sale Made', 'Categories.Imported.Objections', Categories.Imported.Touting Benefits']`

I've tried using list comprehension, as such:

`new_api_df['category_list'] =[item['BucketFullName'] for dictionary in new_api_df['Categories'] for item in dictionary]`

but get the error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

I've also tried apply and list comprehension: 
`new_api_df['category_list'] = new_api_df['Categories'].apply([item['BucketFullName'] for dictionary in new_api_df['Categories'] for item in dictionary])`

but I get the following error: 
`AttributeError: 'Categories.Filters.No Sale Made' is not a valid function for 'Series' object`

I've also tried: `new_api_df['category_list'] = df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: x['BucketFullName'])`

but get the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

new_api_df slices:

new_api_df.loc[0]:

````
Contact            {'Id': 22143866, 'Type': 'Call', 'WavPath': '\...
RecordInfo         {'Id': 22143866, 'RowNumber': 1, 'TotalRowCoun...
Measures           {'ID': 22143866, 'TotalHoldCount': 0, 'Agitati...
Others             {'ConfidenceAverage': 69, 'SequenceID': None, ...
Sections           [{'CallId': 22143866, 'SectionId': 1041, 'Sect...
Categories         [{'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 1953, 'Secti...
Scores             [{'CallId': 22143866, 'ScoreId': 399, 'ScoreNa...
ScoreComponents    [{'CallId': 22143866, 'ScoreComponentId': 4497...```
````

Comment: why not `new_api_df['category_list'] =  df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: x['BucketFullName'])`?

Comment: @ansev I tried that and I get the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: could you show your dataframe? I think you have  a list in each cell of your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Categories':[{'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 1953, 'SectionId': 1256, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Filters.No Sale Made', 'Weight': 1.0}
, {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2016, 'SectionId': 1255, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Imported.Objections', 'Weight': 3.0}
, {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2017, 'SectionId': 1255, 'BucketFullName': 'Categories.Imported.Touting Benefits', 'Weight': 1.0}
]})

df['category_list']=df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['BucketFullName'])
print(df)

#                                          Categories  \
#0  {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 1953, 'Sectio...   
#1  {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2016, 'Sectio...   
#2  {'CallId': 22143866, 'BucketId': 2017, 'Sectio...   
#
#                          category_list  
#0       Categories.Filters.No Sale Made  
#1        Categories.Imported.Objections  
#2  Categories.Imported.Touting Benefits
```

**UPDATE**

Note that this creates a list for each cell.

```
df['category_list']=df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: [m_dict['BucketFullName'] for m_dict in x])
```

then you can use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
df = df.explode('category_list')
#(df['Categories'].apply(lambda x: [m_dict['BucketFullName'] for m_dict in x])                                                             
#                  .explode()) #check the explode serie
```

Comment: ansev suggested that, but I get the error:  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: could you copy and paste in your question a slice of `print(df['categories'])`?

Comment: sure, i can definitely do that

Comment: this shows that in row one for categories there is a list so first you must access the list (for each cell) and then the dictionary contained in the list, if the list has only one dictionary, just do `x[0]['BucketFullName']`

Comment: you should simply be aware of your data and how to iterate through a list / dict

Comment: That would be my next question then, how do I iterate through the values that are containing within a list of dictionaries? x[i]['BucketFullName'] using list comprehension?

Comment: yes you can use list comprehension, see update section

Comment: This was SUPER helpful THANK YOU

Comment: I am glad to help: ) Consider accept my asnwer clicking the tick